# Is it possible to call SSRS 2008 R2 report in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssrs-2008

I designed a report using Business Development Studio 2008 and my reporting server is SQL Server 2008 R2. The .rdl report is ready but is it possible to show this report on a Web Form of Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the report viewer control within ASP.NET.

Comment: Or you can simply IFRAME out a section of your page to point to the report itself on the report server...

Comment: You could also do that. However the control provides more flexibility IMO, i.e. running the report under another account.